# Run several batch files but with exceptions

Tags: bash

I have around `100 files.sh` to run by using:

```
for files in The_job_*;do
sbatch $files;
done
```

but in one of these 100 files I have 5 that I do not want to be ran, so I would like to say something like:

```
for files in The_job_*;do
sbatch $files except for "The_job_345", "The_job_567", "The_job_789";
done
```

Thanks you for your help if you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use extended glob (have a look at the end of the [Pattern Matching section in the reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)) like so:

```
shopt -s extglob

for file in The_job_!(345|567|789); do
    # Don't forget the quotes:
    sbatch "$file"
done
```

Another possibility is:

```
# If using bash 3, you'll need to turn extglob on (uncomment the following line)
# shopt -s extglob

for file in The_job_*; do
    if [[ $file = The_job_@(345|567|789) ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    sbatch "$file"
done
```

If you have lots of files to skip, it's probably easier to declare them in an array or an associative array... but since you only have 5, either of the possibilities I gave you should be alright.

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error: `-bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
-bash: syntax error near `The_test@(4'` when I use: `for file in The_test*; do    if [[ $file = The_test@(4.sh|1.sh) ]]; then `

Comment: @bewolf: that's probably because you're using bash 3. In this case, `shopt -s extglob` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an if to guard `sbatch`.

```c
for files in The_job_*; do
  if ! [[ $files = "The_job_345" || $files = "The_job_567" || $files =  "The_job_789" ]]; then
    sbatch $files;
  fi;
done
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try :`for files in The_job_*; do`
  `if ! [[$files -eq "The_job_2.sh" || $files -eq "The_job_1.sh" || $files -eq  "The_job_3.sh"]]; then`
    `cat $files;`
  `fi;`
`done` I get :  `-bash: [[The_job_1.sh: command not found
JUII-bash: [[The_job_2.sh: command not found
LOPP-bash: [[The_job_3.sh: command not found
Alloui-bash: [[The_job_4.sh: command not found`

Comment: @bewolf: there were some spaces missing around `[[` and `]]`, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Or with a conf file :

```
for files in The_job_*;do
grep $files $FILE_BASH_TO_EXCLUDE >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        msgOut "Do not run this one"
    else
        sbatch $files;
    fi
done
```

With this solution you dont have to edit your code if you add exception ;)

Comment: I don't want to edit your answer as there are too many things to fix: 1. you should quote your parameter expansions; 2. use the `-F` option to grep, so that `"files"` isn't interpreted as a regex; 3. don't use the return of grep like so, instead use `if grep -q ...`; 4. Don't use uppercase variable names. All in all it's better written as `if grep -Fq "$files" "$file_bash_to_exclude"; then ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` statement:

```
for file in The_job_*; do
  case $file in
  The_job_345 | The_job_567 | The_job_789)
    ;;
  *)
    sbatch "$file" ;;
  esac
done
```